# Responsive navigation won't open after using .slideUp()

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, responsive

I'm using the following code to open my responsive navigation and close it when a link is selected:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".burger-nav").on("click", function(){

        $("nav ul").toggleClass("open");

    });

    $("nav li a").on("click", function() {

        $("nav ul").slideUp();

    });
});
```

This works perfectly however once the navigation has closed the nav button doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas? Any help with this would be gratefully appreciated!

The HTML for the nav:

```
<nav id="nav">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="brand">
        <img class="logo" src="img/icons/diamond.png" alt="Danny Hatton Logo"><h1>dannyhatton</h1>
    </div>
        <span class="burger-nav"><img src="img/burger.png" alt="Expand navigation"></span>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#intro" class="slide">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aboutme" class="slide">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contactme" class="slide">Contact Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is the open class still on the nav ul when the slideUp completes?  Might want to removeClass on it when the transition is done.

Comment: Cheers Scott, how would I go about doing that? I'm pretty much a beginner when it comes to JQuery.

Comment: Any chance you could show is your html also?

Comment: @Canvas sure, I've added it to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of slideUp() use **slideToggle()** this will fire both slideUp() and slideDown() even/odd clicks

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $(".burger-nav").on("click", function(){

     $("nav ul").slideToggle();

  });

  $("nav li a").on("click", function() {

      $("nav ul").slideToggle();

   });

});
```

You can hide the menu initially by adding display none to UL

```
<ul style="display:none">
```

And then click on the burger nav it will open the menu and everything will work fine for sure

Demo : https://jsbin.com/zohoqi/3/edit?html,js,console,output

Try this once buddy !!

Comment: Thanks @KrishCdbry I've tested it but unfortunately it doesn't work and provides the same result.

Comment: Just updated code and added demo link have a look at it once dude hope that helps.

Comment: @KrishCdbry just a quick side note, you may want to put in a `.stop()` before the `toggleSlide()`, if the user decides to keep clicking the `Expand navigation` it will just keep sliding up and down

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".burger-nav").on("click", function(){

        $("nav ul").slideToggle();

    });

    $("nav li a").on("click", function() {

        $("nav ul").slideUp();

    });

});
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        
       <nav id="nav">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="brand">
        <img class="logo" src="img/icons/diamond.png" alt="Danny Hatton Logo"><h1>dannyhatton</h1>
    </div>
        <span class="burger-nav"><img src="img/burger.png" alt="Expand navigation"></span>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#intro" class="slide">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aboutme" class="slide">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contactme" class="slide">Contact Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <script>
            
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".burger-nav").on("click", function(){

                $("nav ul").slideToggle();

            });

            $("nav li a").on("click", function() {

                $("nav ul").slideUp();

            });

        });
 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unless I'm completely missing something, which is highly likely, the nav button doesn't activate with this solution. Even though I can see that it works when the code is run. It's the same for the above solution by @KrishCdbry

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone that has helped with this, @KrishCdbry came the closest but below is the resolved script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".burger-nav").on("click", function(){

         $("nav ul").toggleClass("open");

    });

    $("nav li a").on("click", function() {

        $("nav ul").toggleClass();

    });
});
```

The only difference being ("open") after the toggleClass, simple when you know how, eh?